# How to hide a Blogger section if its widget invisible

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, blogger

ok see this code

```
<b:section id='page-list'>
  <b:widget id='PageList1' locked='false' type='PageList' version='2' visible='true'>
  </b:widget>
</b:section>
```

I wanna Hide all section if widget invisible 
I use this code

```
cond='data:widgets.PageList.notEmpty'
```

like this

```
<b:section cond='data:widgets.PageList.notEmpty' id='page-list'>
  <b:widget id='PageList1' locked='false' type='PageList' version='2' visible='true'>
  </b:widget>
</b:section>
```

it's work but whene I add another widget "PageList" than appears again ..
If it can be solved without jq & java ...
just use conditionnelles tag for blogger ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data:widgets.PageList.notEmpty` tests every widget of pageList type in the template. To apply the condition on a specific widget, use the widget id `PageList1` instead of the type.

As the widget id doesn't exist in `data:widgets`, you can do that using a lambada expression

`cond='(data:widgets.PageList filter (w => w.id == "PageList1")).notEmpty'`

Comment: Thank you for your reply :D .
now this condition `data:widgets.PageList.notEmpty` not accept `id` accept just `type`
and this is problem ??

Answer (score 1):

Try the css property visibility: hidden;

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<b:section class="hidden" id='page-list'>
  <b:widget id='PageList1' locked='false' type='PageList' version='2'>
  </b:widget>
</b:section>
```